# android insert $ at start of Textview

Tags: android, textview, currency, symbols

I have a text view name total
I want to add a $ symbol in-front so that when i key in a number in the textview, it will appear as currency, Eg.$20 instead of 20

but at other part of my code later, i will also need to get value from this textview which need to exclude the $ symbol

please show me the easiest way to do this

Thank you

Comment: you can use an image and a left-drawable, or a textview on the left or the edittext.

Comment: use a stringbuilder to concatinate the two parts of the string, then do textview.setText(myString);

Comment: thanks njzk2 and bofredo. it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an icon for the dollar symbol, and set it as the left drawable:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTxtView);
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```